# The type or namespace name could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: visual-studio

My project on my local machine works fine on tfs, but another developer when connecting to the same project the build does not complete and we get the error, "The type or namespace name could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" Not sure what the problem is.

Errors the other machine has are in references (see picture).
[image: Errors the other machine has are in references]

Comment: Read the warnings and errors Visual Studio gives you. You probably refer to an assembly using a path not available on the other machine.

Comment: Restore Nuget packages?

Comment: check the above image that is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can get error when I've manually edited a package version within the `package.json` file. Regardless if this is how you got here, try the solution I have used to resolve this issue:

- unloading the project (via the right-click menu);
- now right-click and edit the `.csproj`; and
- find within the project the reference to package you are looking at, in this case "System.Web.Razor". In the cases that I have had this error it has been because the version inside the `.csproj` has not matched that in the package.json file.

Match the versions, save and then reload the `.csproj` and try again.